# Convert Google Street View urls from OLD to NEW

Tags: google-maps, maps, url, google-street-view

My website accepts google street view links as submissions.
Google has updated the url format some months ago.

Does anybody know how the old format is converted into the new format (and vice versa)?

There are some parts obviously in common, others I cannot associate.
Here is an example of what the urls look like.

OLD:
https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=8.253284,-75.570099&spn=0.18,0.3&cbll=8.253284,-75.570099&layer=c&panoid=5_ZZUCFHDYJsB1ZUtJbNYg&cbp=,42.83,,3,4.169998

NEW:
https://www.google.com/maps/@8.253284,-75.570099,3a,15y,42.83h,85.83t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s5_ZZUCFHDYJsB1ZUtJbNYg!2e0

Comment: I don't think everything in the url is required. there is some good documentation on the old url here (looks like most translates to new version) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387942/google-street-view-url

Comment: Most important is the panoid variable and the camera angle information. The panoid stores the nearest available street view image and allows to always go back to the same image, even if it is no longer available on street view. The panoid is easy to identify in the above urls. More difficult is the camera information (the cbp varialbe in the old url). Without this info, the camera would just point in some random direction, but not in the direction that was recorded in the OLD url.